# Scheduled Mass Email - When is the Query Run?

Tags: email, massemailmessage

I have a drip campaign sending out emails to leads who are NOT unqualified (there are also some more filters)

I generally queue 4 weeks worth of emails so I have a big batch of emails ready to go out.

Now if I change a lead from Open to Unqualified will this already affects leads in the mass email queue - i.e. is the query run just before sending as well as when the mass email is queued?

Or is it only run the once when the mass e-mail is set up.

It seems obvious that it is the first....but it's been bugging me...

Comment: How are you sending out your mass emails? (Time-based workflow, third party solution, etc.)

Comment: For these I'm just using the vanilla mass email function off the contacts tab

Answer (score 1):

On the first step of the mass email wizard, you select a view and a list of leads, and then you select specific records to mail to. *Those are the recipients of your mass email.* Any changes to any lead will not affect the recipient list, which has already been established at the time the email was scheduled for delivery. To change the recipient list, you would have to delete the mailing and re-create it.

For mass email capability that *does* support this type of behavior, you would need to either develop a custom solution in Apex Code, or use a third party mailer, many of which allows you to run the filter conditions immediately before sending the mail, even if it was scheduled (e.g. Exact Target, Vertical Response, Got! Marketing, others). This is usually achieved through the use of Campaigns in salesforce.com.